# how to merge similar values in normalizr function?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, normalizr

I have unusual response from server like this

```
[
   {
      id: 1,
      name: "Alexandr",
      children: [
         {
            id: 2,
            name: "Stephan"
         },
         {
            id: 3,
            name: "Nick"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      id: 4,
      name: "David",
      children: [
         {
            id: 3,
            name: "Nick"
         },
         {
            id: 6,
            name: "Paul"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

i would like to normalize this response to receive a diction with all people. So, i use normalizr go flat this

```
const people= new Schema('people');
people.define({
    Children: arrayOf(people),
    NotOwnChildren: arrayOf(people)
});
let normalized = normalize(response.data, arrayOf(people));
```

but doing like this i get an error 
"When merging two people, found unequal data in their "Children" values. Using the earlier value."
How can i adjust normalizr to merge people with same id (update entities with newest data)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're getting two `people` that have differing values for one of their keys (I'm assuming your example input is truncated).

For Normalizr@2:

You can use a custom [`mergeIntoEntity`](https://github.com/paularmstrong/normalizr#normalizeobj-schema-options) function to resolve the issue manually.

---

For Normalizr@>=3.0.0, you'll need use [`mergeStrategy`](https://github.com/paularmstrong/normalizr/blob/e365e5196b48540b5c95d15b42b70cf4defd78ae/docs/api.md#entitykey-definition---options--).

Comment: Thanks for ur answer